# PHP Workers not working in parallel

Tags: php, windows, multithreading, apache, worker

I've got a problem: Worker threads seem to work serially.
This is a very simple example just for a demonstration a problem.

I initialize my worker threads and run them. It should work in parallel however the result looks like it was processed serially.

**PHP 5.6.12**, **Windows** OS, **Apache** server

**DBWorker**: 
[Which of course extends pThreads Worker class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.worker.php)

```
class DBWorker extends Worker {

    private $str;

    public function __construct($str){
        $this->str = $str;
    }

    public function run(){
        $i=0;
        while($i < 10) {
            echo "$this->str: $i\n";
            $i++;
        }
    }
}
```

**Initialization**:

```
private $DBWorker1;
private $DBWorker2;
private $DBWorker3;

/* ... */

public function __construct(){
    $this->DBWorker1 = new DBWorker("worker1");
    $this->DBWorker2 = new DBWorker("worker2");
    $this->DBWorker3 = new DBWorker("worker3");
}

/* ... */

$this->DBWorker1->start();      
$this->DBWorker2->start();      
$this->DBWorker3->start();      


$i=0;
while($i < 10) {
    echo "parent: $i\n";
    $i++;
}

var_dump($this->DBWorker1->shutdown());
var_dump($this->DBWorker2->shutdown());
var_dump($this->DBWorker3->shutdown());
```

**Result**:

```
parent: 0  
parent: 1  
parent: 2  
...  
parent: 6  
worker1: 0  
worker1: 1  
worker1: 2  
...  
worker1: 59  
worker2: 0  
worker2: 1  
worker2: 2  
...  
worker2: 59  
worker3: 0  
worker3: 1  
worker3: 2  
...  
worker3: 59  
parent: 7
parent: 8  
parent: 9  
bool(true)  
bool(true)  
bool(true)
```

Comment: Yes they do.... PHP executes synchronously..... it executes inside a single thread.... You're not creating individual worker threads, just instantiating multiple classes called worker, and calling methods... why did you think it should work in parallel?

Comment: There are technique you can use to execute blocks of code asynchronously; but they aren't the norm.... look at pthreads, or at something like ReactPHP

Comment: @MarkBaker Worker extends Thread so DBWorker should transitively extends Thread. I have tried pthreads too and the result was almost the same.

Comment: Then explain in more detail what you're doing..... and what this mysterious `Thread` class actually is, or what package or library it comes from..... all the code you've shown is standard PHP OOP, nothing more than that

Comment: @RiggsFolly Worker class is **no** secret. http://php.net/manual/en/class.worker.php The start() method is inherited from Thread and executes run(). The same as thread. All DBWorker class is shown.

Comment: @MarkBaker In this example I just want 3 Threads (Worker: http://php.net/manual/en/class.worker.php extended with Thread http://php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php) and the main one where it is initialized and executed to be printing strings. Sorry, this is my first try of parallelization in PHP. However in Java it's the same, isn't it?

Comment: Are you using [pthread-w32](https://www.sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/)?

Comment: @MarkBaker Yes. I downloaded it here. http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/pthreads/ It causes no Fatal error (before downloading it had been) so I guess it's not the problem.

Comment: No, that's the PHP pthreads extension, not pthread-w32.... you need a posix compliant threaded library (pthread-w32) to run threading on Windows.... pthreads won't run anything in threads if the underlying OS isn't threaded, and pthread-w32 is required to provide native Windows threading

Comment: @MarkBaker Ok. I try it out. Thank you for your willingness.

Comment: Windows binaries for pthreads comes with pthread-w32 binaries included. MCVE required please.